# Why should "aaaaAAAAAA000000123456"take 5 steps and not 6

Tags: algorithm

I was doing this problem on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/strong-password-checker/ and I came across an edge case where `"aaaaAAAAAA000000123456"` was expected to take 5 steps to become a good password, according to the somewhat vague description:

> deleting a character takes one step,
> adding a character takes one step,
> replacing a character takes one step.

The max allowed number of characters is 20 in a "strong" password, and `"aaaaAAAAAA000000123456"` has 22 characters. Repeating 3s like `"aaa"` or `"OOO"` are considered insecure, so to make a password secure, you'd remove, replace or add a new char to one of the characters in the repeating 3s. You also have to make sure there are capital letters, small letters, and numbers in the password to be truly secure.

According to my logic, `"aaaaAAAAAA000000123456"` or `"aaa"+"a" +"AAA"+"AAA"+"000"+"000"+"123456"` (noting the repeating 3s) should take 6 steps to become "secure", not 5:

Step 1: the string is 22 characters, so remove a char from one repeating 3 making; `"aa"+"a"+"AAA"+"AAA"+"000"+"000"+"123456"`

Step 2: it's now 21 chars, so remove another repeating 3 char; `"aa"+"AAA"+"AAA"+"000"+"000"+"123456"`

Step 3: (now 20 chars) replace a repeating 3 char; `"aa"+"A1A"+"AAA"+"000"+"000"+"123456"`

Step 4: replace another repeating 3 (I have to remove all of them); `"aa"+"A1A"+"A2A"+"000"+"000"+"123456"`

Step 5: replace another repeating 3; `"aa"+"A1A"+"A2A"+"030"+"000"+"123456"`

Step 6: remove the last repeating 3; `"aa"+"A1A"+"A2A"+"030"+"040"+"123456"`

Why should this take 5 steps and not 6?

I don't think it's necessary to add my code for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aaaaAAAAAA000000123456
delete A
delete 0
aaaaAAAAA00000123456
replace a
replace A
replace 0
aazaAAzAA00z00123456
```

5 steps total